# Convergence a.e., and measurability

Tags: measure-theory

This is a question I find, but I think is very vague; maybe I shoudn't give an specific sequence of measurable functions and I need to give more conditions. The answer is correct but I'm not sure if it is the answer what it is expected.

> Let $(X, \mathscr A, \mu)$ a measure space and let $\{f_k\}$ a sequence of $\mathscr A $-measurable functions such that $f_k \xrightarrow{a.e} f$. Give conditions for $f_k$ and $\mathscr A$ for $f$ not be $\mathscr A$-measurable.

We may assume that $\mathscr A$ is not complete with respect to $\mu$. So there exists a $\mu$-null set $N$ such that contains a subset $N'$ which does not belong to $\mathscr A$. Now let $f_k = 0$ for all $k$ and let $f= \chi_{N'}$, so $f_k \xrightarrow {a.e} f$. Then $f^{-1} (\{1\})=N'\not \in \mathscr A$. Thus $f$ is not measurable.

Using the adivice of D.Ulrich. The other side is very easy, suppose there exist a sequence $f_k$ of measurable functions such that converge a.e. to a non measurable function $f$. We will show that $\mathscr A$ is not $\mu$-complete. Suppose to the contrary that it is complete.

Let $N$ in $\mathscr A$ such that for all $x$ in $X-N$, $f(x)=\lim f_k(x)$ and $\mu (N)=0$. Let $g(x)= f(x)$ for $x$ in $X-N$ and $0$ otherwise. So $g$ is measurable (since it is in a measurable partition of $X$) and $f=g$ a.e., then $$\{f(x)\le t\}=\{f(x)\le t\}\cap N \cup \{g(x)\le t\}\cap N^c \in \mathscr A$$
thus $f$ is measurable, contradiction.

Comment: The question seems poorly phrased - hard to say exactly what answer is expected. You've shown that there _exist_ $f_k$ and $f$ such that etc if and only if $\mu$ is not complete; I'd accept that if I'd assigned the problem..

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich In fact is a question from an exam. :(, Thank you